# Haskell parse error on input ‘|’ when trying to compile

Tags: haskell

Hi all I'm learning haskell and I made this code to implemente fractions but when I compile it I get the error `parse error on input ‘|’`
My code is the following:

```
module Fraccion(Frac,Div,mcd,fraccion) where


data Frac = Div Integer Integer deriving (Eq, Show)


mcd :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
mcd a b | a > b = mcd (a-b) b
        | a < b = mcd a (b-a)
        | a == b = a

fraccion :: Integer -> Integer -> Frac 
fraccion a b | b == 0 = error "divisor can't be 0"
             | b <  0 = fraccion (-a) (-b)
             | b >  0 = Div (a `div` mcdab) (b `div` mcdab)
                        where mcdab = mcd (abs a) b

instance (Num Frac) where
    negate (Div a b)      = (Div (-a) b)
    abs    (Div a b)      = (Div (abs a) b)
    (Div a b) * (Div c d) = fraccion (a*c) (b*d)
    (Div a b) + (Div c d) = fraccion (a*d+b*c) (b*d)
    (Div a b) - (Div c d) = fraccion (a*d-b*c) (b*d)
    fromInteger n = (Div n 1)
    signum (Div a b) | a > 0 = 1
                     | a < 0 + -1
                     | a == b = 0

instance show Frac where
    show (Div a b) = (show a) ++ "/" ++ (show b)
```

Could you please help me with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Line 27:

```
| a < 0 + -1
```

A simple typo. You put `+` where you meant `=`

```
| a < 0 = -1
```

You'll also want to capitalize `show` on the second-to-last line. Your `deriving` clause for your type shouldn't include `Show` either, because you define an instance explicitly rather than deriving it. Finally, your module export list should look like this.

```
module Fraccion(Frac(Div),mcd,fraccion) where
```

Comment: when I fix that I get this error: `Not in scope: type variable ‘show’
    Perhaps you meant type constructor or class ‘Show’ (imported from Prelude)`

Comment: Capitalize `show` on the second-to-last line. These are quite simple typographical errors. Remember that GHC tells you the line number to look at to fix the problem. You can usually sort out typos like this pretty easily once you know the line number.

Comment: @Deindery There are several little typographical errors like that in your posted code. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, now my code works after I remove all the auto tabs and fix the typos